# How to tell PhpStorm / WebStorm that some argument has to be a CSS selector?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phpstorm, code-completion

I want to use jQuery-like shorthands for the JavaScript methods `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. At least I've already managed that PhpStorm understands the return results on completion. However, I've got no clue how to get completion work in the CSS-selector string argument.

```
/** @typedef {function (selectors:string):NodeList|null} FnQuerySelectorAll */
/** @typedef {function (selectors:string):Element      } FnQuerySelector    */

(d =>
{
  const
    /** @type FnQuerySelectorAll */ 
    $  = (Document.prototype.$  = Document.prototype.querySelectorAll).bind(d),

    /** @type FnQuerySelector    */
    $1 = (Document.prototype.$1 = Document.prototype.querySelector   ).bind(d)
  ;
  Element.prototype.$           = Element .prototype.querySelectorAll;
  Element.prototype.$1          = Element .prototype.querySelector   ;
  // ...
})(document)
```

When I type `document.$('`, actually, I do get selector completions.
When I type `$('`, it does not behave in the same way.

PhpStorm does not recognize the functions built by the `bind` method. I'm not very familiar with JSDoc. Is there any possibility to tell PhpStorm that the string argument has to be a CSS selector or the whole function is an alias for another one?

Comment: Please do not start discussions about monkey patching. I'm aware of the pros/cons. :)

Comment: jQuery is open source, so you could always "cheat" and peek in there to see how they tackle it.

Comment: @tadman There's a JQuery support plugin in PHPStorm.

Comment: @tadman What does the jQuery source have to do with this? This is coming from the IDE configuration.

Comment: @Barmar I mean the implementation for jQuery's code highlighter whatever. These rules can be pretty convoluted, but if there's a working one for jQuery use that, with adaptations.

Comment: AFAIK, none of that comes from the jQuery library itself. Intellij has its own  configuration files with the declarations of all the functions it knows how to auto-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now managed the issue by configuring PhpStorm.

- Open the PhpStorm settings.
- Navigate to *"Editor > Language Injections"*.
- Edit the entry *"js:DOM element selectors"*.

The original "Places Pattern" was:

```
+ jsArgument(jsReferenceExpression().withReferenceNames("querySelector", "querySelectorAll", "closest"), 0)
```

Change it to:

```
+ jsArgument(jsReferenceExpression().withReferenceNames("querySelector", "querySelectorAll", "closest", "$", "$1"), 0)
```

Now PphStorm recognizes the first argument of the functions `$` and `$1` as a CSS selector string.

Note: Although this settings page is marked as per project basis, the scope of the rule has the scope *IDE* by default. Thus it **will affect all other projects** as well.

As mentioned by *@LazyOne*, it could be more desirable to duplicate the original rule and change your own copy to:

```
+ jsArgument(jsReferenceExpression().withReferenceNames("$", "$1"), 0)
```

You can move your modified custom copy to project scope by using the buttons above the list if you want.

Comment: A (better) suggestion: 1) Make a copy of that original rule. 2) Edit it so it can be applied to your methods only. 3) Save it, change the scope to "IDE" if desired (so it will be available in all projects on this computer)

Comment: @LazyOne Due to your comment I just realized that this entry actually is in the scope IDE  although the setting page is marked as per project. Separating presets and custom settings is a good point. I'll extend my answer.